# paraview python script : Delete(renderView1) does not free memory

Tags: python, paraview

I am trying to load multiple state files by running a python script with python shell. The script is the following

```css
#### import the simple module from the paraview
from paraview.simple import *

for time in range(0,200):
        renderView1 = GetActiveViewOrCreate('RenderView')

        # destroy renderView1
        Delete(renderView1)
        del renderView1

        filename = 'filepath/filename-%s.pvsm' % time
        servermanager.LoadState(filename)
        renderView=SetActiveView(GetRenderView())
        Render()
        # get layout
        viewLayout = GetLayout()

        # save screenshot
        SaveScreenshot('filepath/filename-%s.png' % time, layout=viewLayout, magnification=3, quality=100)
```

I was monitoring the memory used by machine, after some time steps the memory used by the machine is whole RAM. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here.

I appreciate your time and support.

Thanks
Raj

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by [Utkarsh](http://www.kitware.com/blog/home/user/48) the following script solved my problem. For details see this [answer](https://www.mail-archive.com/paraview@paraview.org/msg24237.html).

```css
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
from paraview.simple import *

def ResetSession():
    pxm = servermanager.ProxyManager()
    pxm.UnRegisterProxies()
    del pxm
    Disconnect()
    Connect()

for i in range(0, 10):
    ResetSession()
    servermanager.LoadState("/tmp/sample.pvsm")
    renderView=SetActiveView(GetRenderView())
    Render()
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

Python is garbage-collected, which means that there are no guarantees that an object is actually removed from memory when you do 'del someBigObject'. In fact, doing 'del someObject' is not only pointless, it's considered bad style.

`del` only removes the binding between that identifier and the object. Thus `del` doesn't actually result in the object being deleted from memory.

See this for full details:
https://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-Python-release-the-memory-when-I-delete-a-large-object

Comment: The question is that why is important the memory consumption for you, does it slow down some other process and is this memory load real or just virtual? From what do you get the information regarding the memory load?