# Paraview programmatically Reset Session

Tags: python, paraview

In Paraview, one can do Edit -> Reset Session.
It brings a clean state.

**How can that be done programmatically, from a python script?
I mean it to work for both the GUI (at the python shell and as a macro) and CLI (`pvpython`).**

PS: I wouldn't know what are the differences between Reset Session and closing / reopening Paraview.
I did not test it thoroughly, but in all I could observe, they behave the same.

PS2: I am currently using a contrived way, but it is not quite equivalent to Reset Session.

```
def reset_session() :
    RemoveViewsAndLayouts()
    clear_pipeline()
    return

def clear_pipeline() :
    srcs = GetSources()
    for key, val in srcs.items() :
        #print( "key = " + str(key) + ", value = " + str(val) )
        #print( "   (" + str(type(key)) + "),  (" + str(type(val)) + ")" )
        Delete(val)
        del val
    return
```

PS3: I tested an answer with this minimal code, executed from the GUI from Macros -> mymacro, and it crashes.

```
Disconnect()
Connect()
```

Comment: It crashed indeed as a macro, not when using the python shell. That is unexpected and definitelly a bug.

Comment: https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/issues/17970

Answer (score 4):

For ParaView <= 5.7.1 : Reset Session remove all the proxies. It is really close to closing reopening the application and can be considered as such.

To do that in Python, since ResetSession is not implemented, use the following :

```
Disconnect()
Connect()
```

Comment: your macro is not equivalent to Disconnecting and Reconnecting. I would suggest taking a look into the other issue:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31423347/paraview-python-script-deleterenderview1-does-not-free-memory

Comment: I found in my notes that https://public.kitware.com/pipermail/paraview/2015-July/034588.html mentioned a related method, and I tried it before with no success.

Comment: Did you test this in either GUI or CLI and it worked with no errors?

Comment: this works in the ParaView GUI python shell, as well as in pvpython and it works perfectly. It crashes only within a Macro.

Answer (score 2):

ParaView 5.8.0 now has a `ResetSession()` method.

Comment: Great! I will try it.